# Django, "Can't adapt type error", Sqlite vs Postresql

Tags: python, django

I am using [django-phonenumber-field](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-phonenumber-field/) battery for my django app (django 1.9, python 3.5).

I have form like follows:

```
class PhoneChangeForm(forms.Form):

    phonenumber = PhoneNumberField(widget=PhoneNumberPrefixWidget(attrs={'placeholder': _('Phone number')}),
                                    label=_("Enter phone"))

    def clean_phonenumber(self):
        users = User.objects.filter(profile__phone__iexact=self.cleaned_data['phonenumber'])
        if users.count() == 0:
            return self.cleaned_data['phonenumber']
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("This phone is already in use."))
```

In my development environment this form works normally. If there is user with given phone number then ValidationError is raised.

When I am moving the same code into Production I have following error:

```
Django Version:     1.9.6
Exception Type:     ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    can't adapt type 'PhoneNumber'
```

Creators don't respond to the last comments so I decided to ask here. Can you suggest the best way to debug it

Comment: Have you done pip install django-phonenumber-field on your production environment? Are you using a custom user model to store the user with phonenumber?

Comment: sure, it is in!

Comment: If you're using sqlite3 in the production environment then it will try to store it as a string. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510529/django-cant-adapt-type-error-using-mutliple-databases-postgresql-8-4-and-sql

Comment: yes, you are right. I just was checking the solution based in this answer and it is working. I will update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Production I am using Postresql, for development Sqlite.
Based on this [answer][2] there is some kind of bug in Django's filter depending on DB backend. If to use Sqlite then:

```
User.objects.filter(profile__phone__iexact=self.cleaned_data['phonenumber'])
```

is working like a charm.

If to use Postrgres it will throw "can't adapt type". Converting the value into string explicitly will solve the problem:

```
users = User.objects.filter(profile__phone__iexact=str(self.cleaned_data['phonenumber']))
```